# get query behind each executorservice thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using executorsevice in JAVA to execute some threads, let’s say ten threads, number of threads may vary. Each thread is executing a SQL server query. I am using Future and Callable classes to submit the tasks. I am getting the results [using future.get()] once each thread is finished.

Now my requirement is that I need to know the query which is executed by each thread once its result is returned, even if the result is an empty set.

Here is my code:

```
List<Future<List>> list = new ArrayList<Future<List>>();
    int totalThreads = allQueriesWeight.size();
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreads);
    for (String query : allQueriesWeight) {//allQueriesWeight is an arraylist containing sql server queries
        SearchTask searchTask = new SearchTask(query);
        Future<List> submit = taskExecutor.submit(searchTask);
        list.add(submit);
    }
```

Here is my call function:

```
@Override
public List<SearchResult> call() throws Exception {
    java.sql.Statement statement = null;
    Connection co = null;
    List<SearchResult> allSearchResults = new ArrayList();
    try {
        //executing query and getting results
        while (r1.next()) {
            ...
            allSearchResults.add(r);//populating array
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (co != null) {
            co.close();
        }
    }
    return allSearchResults;
}
```

Here is how I am getting the results:

```
for (Future<List> future : list) {
        try {
            System.out.println(future.get().size());
            List<SearchResult> sr = future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

In this above for loop, I need to identify the query of which the result is returned. I am a newbie and any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The `list` will contain the results in exactly the same order in which you submitted the queries to the Executor, so you can match them up with `allQueriesWeight`.

Comment: But your SeatchTask was passed the query? So you might want to pass it into SearchResult as well?

Comment: Isn't it simple enough for you to define a class holding both the execution result list as well as any performance measurements i.e. the thread ID the execution time etc ? Then you can return that class object as result of your `callable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative 1:**
You have both the lists in the same order and of same size, so you can simple do as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < allQueriesWeight.size(); i++) {
    allQueriesWeight.get(i);
    futureList.get(i);
}
```

**Alternative 2:**
If all the queries are different, you can use a map as shown below but this approach will lose the order of execution.

```
int totalThreads = allQueriesWeight.size();
Map<String,Future<List>> map = new HashMap<>;
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreads);
for (String query : allQueriesWeight) {//allQueriesWeight is an arraylist containing sql server queries
    SearchTask searchTask = new SearchTask(query);
    Future<List> submit = taskExecutor.submit(searchTask);
    map.put(query ,submit );
}
```

And then iterate the map

```
for (Entry<String,Future<List>> future : map.) {
    System.out.println("query is:" +map.getKey());
    List<SearchResult> sr = map.getValue().get();

}
```

**Alternative 3**
If you want to keep the order, create  a class with Future and query as the attributes and then put that class in list

```
   public class ResultWithQuery {

    private final Future<List<?>> future;
    private final  String query;


    public ResultWithQuery(Future<List<?>> future, String query) {
        this.future = future;
        this.query = query;
    }


    public Future<List<?>> getFuture() {
        return future;
    }


    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

}
```

And

```
List<ResultWithQuery > list = new ArrayList<ResultWithQuery >();
    int totalThreads = allQueriesWeight.size();
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreads);
    for (String query : allQueriesWeight) {//allQueriesWeight is an arraylist containing sql server queries
        SearchTask searchTask = new SearchTask(query);
        Future<List> submit = taskExecutor.submit(searchTask);
        list.add(new ResultWithQuery (submit, query));
    }
```

And iterate the list

```
for (ResultWithQuery resQuery: list) {
        try {
            resQuery.getQuery();
            List<SearchResult> sr = resQuery.getFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what is was looking for. It solved my problem. Thank you so much for detailed answer.